# Navigation bar automatically goes to top

Tags: html, css

When I scroll down, the `position` of the navigation bar is `fixed`. But there is space on top of it. How to make it automatically go to the top?

http://jsfiddle.net/q236h/

Comment: I dont find any problem as such.`How to make it automatically go to the top?`, what do u mean by this question, is it like making a button, clicking on which the page re-navigate to the top, or any thing else? please make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, I've always resorted to using JS. jQuery made the whole thing very easy. My `<nav>` is positioned normally, until the it hits the top edge of the viewport. Then it gets the "fixed" class added to it, which positions it fixed at 0 0. When scrolling back up, the class gets removed again, and the `<nav>` falls back to its original position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var navOffset = $('nav').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > navOffset) {
            $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });

});
```

A live example can be viewed [here](http://crshd.github.io). I guess that's what you wanted to achieve? Your question is not quite clear. [/shameless self promotion]

Comment: how do i insert this? @crshd

Comment: Add a CSS class:
    nav.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; 
    }

And add the JS code, and include jQuery. If anybody knows a more lightweight solution that doesn't require jQuery, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

use this css . this will solve your problem. Change the position to "absolute" for nav .

```
nav {
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
font-family: Georgia;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: If he uses `absolute` - he would also need `top:0;left:0`